# Get all tables from database, if the table has some records present

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to get all the tables, with a condition that if table is not empty(if it has some records present).

I can get the list of tables with :

```
USE 'DatabaseName'
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_Schema = 'dbo'
ORDER BY table_NAME.
```

But, I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_Schema = 'dbo'
    AND "**table has some records present**" ORDER BY table_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(T.OBJECT_ID) AS TABLE_NAME,
        SUM(P.ROWS)  AS TOTAL_ROWS
FROM
        sys.tables T
INNER JOIN 
        sys.partitions P 
        ON T.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
        P.INDEX_ID IN (0,1)
GROUP BY 
        T.OBJECT_ID
HAVING 
        SUM(P.ROWS) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

run this

```
select 'select count(*) [entries],'''+ TABLE_NAME + ''' from '+ quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(TABLE_NAME) + ' union' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

to get a list of every table and the number of entries in that table then you can put that into a temp table and look for anything where entries >1.

Remember to remove the union at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
   ( 
    SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
    ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
    FROM sys.tables ta
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
    ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
    ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
    WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
    GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
    ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
) as T where RowCnt>0
```

More  help can get you from [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/08/sql-server-find-row-count-in-table-find-largest-table-in-database-part-2/)